# Python 3: Comparing tuples in a master list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare, tuples

Alright, this has been the source of a major headache for me. I have a list, and each element in the list is a tuple, and each tuple contains exactly two elements (a string, and a dictionary).

Here is a comparable list:

```
list_of_tuples = [ ('one':{'a':'b'}), ('one':{'c':'b'}), ('two':{'a':'b'}), ('two':{'d':'e'}), ('three':{'d':'e'}) ]
```

I am trying to build a network graph, and in this case 'one', 'two' and 'three' correspond to different nodes on the network. There is a tuple for each interface on each node. The dictionary represents the network address and subnet mask. For an interface (one of the tuples) to be connected to another interface is when both interfaces share the same network address and subnet mask (their dictionaries are identical).

Ultimately, I'd like to end up with a new list of tuples, with the elements of the new tuples to simply be the two tuples that represent connected interfaces from the original list.

In other words, I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
list_of_connections = [( ('one':{'a':'b'}),('two':{'a':'b'}) ),  ( ('two':{'d':'e'}),('three':{'d':'e'}) )]
```

I am hitting a brick wall trying to figure out how to achieve this. Does anybody have any input on how this would be accomplished? Note that presently, high performance is not the top priority. The original list does not always have to contain exactly 5 interfaces, and there does not always have to be exactly two connections.

EDIT:

I came up with the following solution, although it is less efficient than the one posted by Manoj.

```
connections = list()

for i in range(len(list_of_tuples)):
    for k in range(len(list_of_tuples)):
        if connections.count((list_of_tuples[k],list_of_tuples[i])) == 0 and ((list_of_tuples[i][1] == list_of_tuples[k][1]) and (list_of_tuples[i][0] != list_of_tuples[k][0])):
            connections.append((list_of_tuples[i],list_of_tuples[k]))
```

Comment: Your tuples should actually be ('one',{'a':'b'}) ... correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string and a dictionary, you should have ('one', {'a':'b'}) and not ('one':{'a':'b'}). With ('one':{'a':'b'}), Python is probably expecting a dictionary. The above code actually should lead you to syntax errors.

If you want to build list_of_connections as a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a string and dictionary, then here is what you can use

```
list_of_tuples = [ ('one', {'a':'b'}), ('one', {'c':'b'}), ('two', {'a':'b'}), ('two', {'d':'e'}), ('three', {'d':'e'}) ]
```

One simple approach would be to collect all the nodes using the (address:subnet) tuple as a key for the dictionary and the value of this key would be a list. This would ensure that all elements with the same address/subnet combination are put in the same bucket. Next, you can iterate over the dictionary values to create a list of lists. I would try this:

```
connections = {}
for elem in list_of_tuples:
    new_key = (list(elem[1].keys())[0], list(elem[1].values())[0])
    if (new_key in connections):
       connections[new_key].append(elem)
    else:
       connections[new_key] = [elem]

list_of_connections = []
for k, v in connections.items():
    list_of_connections.append(v)

print(list_of_connections)
```

The output is:

```
[[('one', {'a': 'b'}), ('two', {'a': 'b'})], [('one', {'c': 'b'})], [('two', {'d': 'e'}), ('three', {'d': 'e'})]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just came up with a solution as well but in comparison with yours, it is very inefficient. I will post my solution to my main question just for reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_of_tuples = [ ('one',{'a':'b'}), ('one',{'c':'b'}), ('two',{'a':'b'}), ('two',{'d':'e'}), ('three',{'d':'e'}) ]

found = []
matches = []
for name, conn in list_of_tuples:

    finder = [(first, second) for first, second in found if second == conn]
    if len(finder) == 1:      
        matches.append(((name, conn), finder[0]))
    else:
        found.append((name, conn))



print matches
```

Outputs:

```
[(('two', {'a': 'b'}), ('one', {'a': 'b'})), (('three', {'d': 'e'}), ('two', {'d': 'e'}))]
```

I believe that is what you were looking for...I am a bit slow, but I figured I may as well finish it lol.